# How to search for a specific dynamic pattern of a field's in mongodb.?

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb

I need to search mongodb collection for a specific pattern field. I tried using {$exists:true}; However, this gives results only if you provide exact field.

I tried using {$exists:true} for my field. But this does not give results if you give some pattern.

```
{
"field1":"value1",
"field2":"value2",
"field3":object
{/arjun1/pat1: 1,
/arjun2/pat2: 3,
/arjun3/pat3: 5
}
"field4":"value4",
}
```

From some field, I get the keys pat3 & field3. From this I would need to find out if the value /arjun3/pat3 exists in the document.
If I use {"field3./arjun3/pat3":{$exists:true}}, this would give me results. But the problem is I get only field3 and pat3 and I need to use some pattern matching like field3.*.pat3 and then use $expr or $exists; which I'm not exactly sure how to. Please help.

Comment: Hi Arjun, you can use aggregation query along with unwind option, match the query and get respective output. Also it will be helpful if you mention exact queries you want to run.

Comment: Hi Priyanka, from a set of documents like the one mentioned above, I would need to create a query which would result me the documents which has the field name *pat3*. But I wouldn't know if its going to /arjun3/pat3 or /arjun2/pat3. All i know is i've pat3 and would need to fetch documents which has values like /arjun1/pat3 , /arjun3/pat3 etc. and not fetch /arjun3/pat2.

Comment: Hi Arjun, I am just thinking out loud here, have you tried using elematch in this case

Comment: No Priyanka. I've never heard of it. Maybe my ignorance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try something of this kind

```
db.arjun.find(
    {"field3" : {
        "$elemMatch" : { $and: [
            {"arjun3.pat3" : {$exists:true}},
            {"arjun3.pat3" : 5}
        ]
        }}}
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either go for regex (`re` module) for SQL like pattern matching, and compile your own custom wildcard. But if you don't want that then you can simple use the `fnmatch` module, it is a builtin library of python which allows wildcard matching for multiple characters (via`*`) or a single character (via `?`).

```
import fnmatch

a = "hello"
print(fnmatch.fnmatch(a, "h*"))
```

**OUTPUT:-**

```
True
```